# React: Необходимо создать форму обратной связи

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо создать форму обратной связи:
Она должна включать в себя поле `email` пользователя, поле ввода feedBack'a в виде `textarea`
Также добавьте чекбокс, согласен или не согласен пользователь на получение спам рассылки

На сабмит необходимо вызывать `fetch` с передачей данных на любой `url/feedbacks`
Вынесите функцию отправки данных в отдельную функцию в отдельном файле `feedback` в отдельной папке `api`
получение функции в компоненте с формой должно выглядить примерно так:

```js
import {sendFeedBack} from "../api/feedBack";
```

форму обратной связи сделал, сабмит тоже. Как сделать это: Вынесите функцию отправки данных в отдельную функцию в отдельном файле `feedback` в отдельной папке `api`
получение функции в компоненте с формой должно выглядить примерно так:

```js
import {sendFeedBack} from "../api/feedBack";
```

Comment: В чем собственно состоит вопрос? В вашем тексте ни одного знака вопроса нет...

Comment: Как сделать это: Вынесите функцию отправки данных в отдельную функцию в отдельном файле feedback в отдельной папке api получение функции в компоненте с формой должно выглядить примерно так: import {sendFeedBack} from "../api/feedBack"?

Comment: Создете файл, пишите в нем фукнцию, далее пишите `export { sendFeedBack }` в нужном файле импортируете фукнцию, как указано у вас и используете в нужном месте кода